# Salesforce Marketing cloud Automation to remove leading zeros

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a text field with data- `00000001000` and `-00000001000`
I am trying to remove all the leading zeros from string field.

I tried using REPLACE function:

`REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([dollarbalance], '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')`

...but it is not giving expected result.

In Query Studio query runs but in Automation it is failing. Also in Query Studio minus sign is not getting ignored and I am getting the same result for value `-00000001000`

Thanks

I tried

`REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE([dollarbalance], '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')`

and

`substring(DOLLARBALANCE, patindex('%[^0]%',DOLLARBALANCE),5)`

Comment: Please update your question to include the data types of the source DE and target DE fields.

Comment: Don't conflate Query Studio and Query Activities.  Query Studio doesn't support everything that you can do in a Query Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any details about the datatypes inbound or outbound, I'd suggest experimenting outside of SFMC, since this really isn't a question specific to the platform.

```sql
declare @dollarbalance varchar(50) = '- 000000000'

select 
  @dollarbalance dollarbalanceRaw
, REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(@dollarbalance, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0') dollarbalanceTemp
, convert(decimal(19,2),@dollarbalance) dollarbalanceDec
, convert(decimal(19,0),@dollarbalance) dollarbalanceNoDec
```

| dollarbalanceRaw | dollarbalanceTemp | dollarbalanceDec | dollarbalanceNoDec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - 000000000 | -0000000000 | 0.00 | 0 |

Try it yourself: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WgDKfdpS)

Reference:

- [Convert function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Hi Adam @Adam Spriggs thank you for the explanation! The source DE field data type is 'TEXT' and destination DE has data type as Decimal.

However I tried using replace function but unfortunately it was erroring out.

Comment: I'd suggest using the convert function.  Please experiment with the fiddle I provided: https://dbfiddle.uk/WgDKfdpS